# Do you need a previous node pointer to implement a Queue?

Tags: javascript, linked-list, stack, queue

I am looking for some clarification / confirmation here.

To my understanding, a Stack can be implemented with a Singly Linked List because all stack operations are performed on the top (head) of the stack. In other words, every stack node only needs a pointer to the `next` node.

However, in a Queue, we need to perform operations at both the front and the back of the queue (ie. enqueue() and dequeue()). Does that mean, that a proper Queue implementation must be built on a Doubly Linked List (ie. a Linked List where each node has both a `next` and `previous` pointer)?

Thanks!

Comment: Already answered, but the operations at both the front and back are limited to push_front() and pop_back(). There could also be peek operations, such as peek_back(), and while peek_front() is possible, it would be unusual.

Answer (score 0):

For Queue, you can implement with Singly Linked List by using 2 pointers: one for the head and one for the tail. So, No need to use Doubly Linked List.
This is the implementation I took from [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/queue-linked-list-implementation/):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 
  
struct QNode { 
    int data; 
    QNode* next; 
    QNode(int d) 
    { 
        data = d; 
        next = NULL; 
    } 
}; 
  
struct Queue { 
    QNode *front, *rear; 
    Queue() 
    { 
        front = rear = NULL; 
    } 
  
    void enQueue(int x) 
    { 
  
        // Create a new LL node 
        QNode* temp = new QNode(x); 
  
        // If queue is empty, then 
        // new node is front and rear both 
        if (rear == NULL) { 
            front = rear = temp; 
            return; 
        } 
  
        // Add the new node at 
        // the end of queue and change rear 
        rear->next = temp; 
        rear = temp; 
    } 
  
    // Function to remove 
    // a key from given queue q 
    void deQueue() 
    { 
        // If queue is empty, return NULL. 
        if (front == NULL) 
            return; 
  
        // Store previous front and 
        // move front one node ahead 
        QNode* temp = front; 
        front = front->next; 
  
        // If front becomes NULL, then 
        // change rear also as NULL 
        if (front == NULL) 
            rear = NULL; 
  
        delete (temp); 
    } 
}; 
  
// Driven Program 
int main() 
{ 
  
    Queue q; 
    q.enQueue(10); 
    q.enQueue(20); 
    q.deQueue(); 
    q.deQueue(); 
    q.enQueue(30); 
    q.enQueue(40); 
    q.enQueue(50); 
    q.deQueue(); 
    cout << "Queue Front : " << (q.front)->data << endl; 
    cout << "Queue Rear : " << (q.rear)->data; 
} 
// This code is contributed by rathbhupendra
```

Answer (score 0):

No. We can implement queue from singly link list as well. We just need to keep the trace of memory addresses of the first and the last element which we can do via pointers.